# How to add an item to Vim context menu?

Tags: vimscript

I want to add a new item to Vim context menu. I select a word, right click on the word, select the new menu item, auto delete rows contain selected word.

How should i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The menu you are referring to is called "PopUp". To create new menu entries you use the command `menu` (It has all the same variations as `map`, plus a special one `amenu` for all modes)

The following command will add a PopUp menu that will delete all rows containing the word under the cursor when you right click.

```
noremenu PopUp.Delete\ Rows :<c-u>g/\<<c-r><c-w>\>/d<cr>
```

So this creates an menu entry called "Delete Rows", when you click it will run `:<c-u>g/\<<c-r><c-w>\>/d<cr>`. The command it is running is a global command that deletes every line that contains the word under the cursor. The word under the cursor is retrieved with `<c-r><c-w>`.

To change the location in the list you need to modify the priority of the menu command. To do this you can place `.<number>`. (The dot represents that we are in a submenu). The number represents how high in the list the menu item will be. So

```
noremenu .1 PopUp.Delete\ Rows :<c-u>g/\<<c-r><c-w>\>/d<cr>
```

will probably be placed first in the list.

To find out the priorities of the entries in the PopUp menu you can run

```
menu PopUp
```

and look at the numbers left of the menu item. If you don't specify a priority, the menu item will be assigned a priority of 500.

Required readings `:help menu`, `:help sub-menu-priority`, `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W` and `:help :global`.

---

After doing all of this, you should take note that learning how to use vim commands would be faster. For instance all you need to do is hit `*` on the word you want to delete and then run `:g//d` to delete all lines containing that word. `*` searches for the word under the cursor, and if you leave out the regex in `g` it uses the last search.